# Rails 4 - How do I use dynamic div ids from div_for in a js.erb file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a Rails app in which I have a list of items. Each item have it's own like button. When clicking this like button I perform some Ajax / Javascript to update the status. I'm having some issues with getting the correct button to update.

My like button looks like this:

```
div_for(idea) do
  - if current_user.voted_for? idea
    = render "ideas/unlike_button", idea: idea
  - else
    = render "ideas/like_button", idea: idea
```

My like.js.erb file currently looks like this:

```
$("#<%= idea_#{@idea.id} %>").html("<%= j render partial:  'ideas/unlike_button', locals: {idea: @idea} %>");
```

I don't think this is working as I want: `"#<%= idea_#{@idea.id} %>"`

What I want is `"idea_123"`.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: First of all, what is going wrong? Is the call being made to the server correctly? Is the correct idea getting voted for? Is the template being rendered for the correct idea? Can the template find the div you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
$("#<%= idea_#{@idea.id} %>").html("Your code");
```

Try:

```
$("#idea_<%= @idea.id %>").html("your code");
```